# Error updating Postgresql from Matlab

Tags: matlab, postgresql

I'm very new to Matlab and I'm trying to update a cell into a Postgresql table.

This is my code

```
s=size(o,1);

for n=1:1:s

colnames={'obj_state_new'};
data = {num2str(2)};
tablename = 'objects';    
whereclause = ['WHERE obj_name = "obj', num2str(n), '"']
update(conn,tablename,colnames,data,whereclause)
end
```

But all I get is this error:

> Error using database/update (line 268)
>   Java exception occurred:
>   java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Batch entry 0 UPDATE objects SET obj_state_new = '2' WHERE obj_name = "obj1" was aborted.  Call getNextException to see the
>   cause.
>       at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement$BatchResultHandler.handleError(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:2762)
>       at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1999)
>       at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:421)
>       at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeBatch(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:2929)
>
> Error in scriptingTest (line 18)
>       update(conn,tablename,colnames,data,whereclause)

I tested the connection and it's OK.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

> `UPDATE objects SET obj_state_new = '2' WHERE obj_name = "obj1"`

The problem are the double quotes around the value.

String literals need to be enclosed in **single** quotes. Double quotes are for identifiers.

So the resulting where clause should look like this:

```
where obj_name = 'obj1'
```

**not** `where obj_name = "obj1"`